# Javafx ImageView with scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm trying to preview different images (depends on the file name) using ImageView, but for some reason it loads the image without previewing it.

```
public void imageRec(){   //method called upon when the file is changed
    String imfichier = resources[track].getName();  //gets the name of the current song
    String imName = imfichier.substring(0, imfichier.lastIndexOf("."));  //removes the ".mp3" extension from the current song 

    File ff = new File("cover/" + imName + ".png");  //loads the image
    image = new Image(ff.toURI().toString());
    cover.setImage(image); //Should preview the image but nothing happens
    cover.setCache(true);  //cover is the fx:id of ImageView
}
```

I know that I can load the url in the *.fxml* file directly, but then I won't be able to change the image if I do that. Any advice?

Comment: You want to see the image your code puts in there on a certain user interaction in the WYSIWYG editor without assigning it's value via fxml?

Comment: No, I want to change the current value with the new value given in my _ff_ variable in oder to display the image.